# How to calculate image as plane position to the camera in order to render the whole image or a part of the image?

Tags: python, camera, image

I am trying to build a python script that places a image as plane object (add-on) programmatically in function of the resolution of the camera.

There are two cases :

1- The image ratio and the camera ratio are the same so i want to place the image as plane so that when i render the scene the image takes full space of the frame.

2- The image ratio of the image is different so i want to place the image as plane so that the camera points to the center of the image and takes a part of the image so that the rendering takes full space of the frame.

If you have any idea of how to do it, i ll be great help.

Thanks.

Comment: you might want to look at the script  on http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?300436-Scripts-Create-camera-image-plane&highlight=camera%20plane

Comment: Thanks for the link, i tried the addon, it is almost what i am looking. Nevertheless it does not use image as plane addon so i get a plane that is not with the image aspect ratio. I will study the script to understand how the distance is calculated.

Comment: Note that the plane created with this add-on can be edited in edit mode, so changing the aspect ratio is quite easy.